# Bundling resources via bundle.config vs BundleConfig.cs in ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.5

Regarding ASP.NET 4.5's new System.Web.Optimization / Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization:

Can anyone explain the difference in the use of bundling resources using the **BundleConfig.cs** class file as opposed to the **bundle.config** xml file?

I've seen some [articles](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/197/Optimising-ASP.NET-Web-Pages-Sites-Bundling-And-Minification) showing bundling both js and css in BundleConfig.cs, while [others](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) showing bundling js in BundleConfig.cs and css in bundle.config.

I guess I don't understand #1) why you wouldn't just do them both one particular way for simplicity - and #2) why anyone would prefer to hard-code resources like that in a class file?  It seems like a much more dynamic approach to just put them in an xml file that can be changed on-the-fly if necessary.

It seems like more articles actually lean toward using BundleConfig.cs than anything else.  Is there some particular pro or con that encourages this?

Also, if there is any real documentation on System.Web.Optimization, I would love to know the location (because I sure can't find it).

Thanks-

Comment: I see that you marked this as answered but I find the answer your marked doesn't really answer the question. I've read the article and the links it includes and nowhere does it explain why you'd use the class file over the config file or vice versa. Did I miss something in the article or links?

Comment: well..  to be honest, i don't know that it really did 100%.  I basically took it to mean that using the class allowed the framework to do more dynamic things like swapping from minified-to-non-minified based on debug, replacing {version}, etc..  whereas the xml file was more static.  but I did not actually take time to test that theory as I wound up going a different direction.  CSS is what i was primarily interested in bundling and minifying, and i'm basically now doing that via the Web Essentials plugin and LESS @import's.

Comment: No, that's not true. The support for auto-swapping minified files and using the {version} placeholder work with the bundle.config file as well. In fact, the framework parses the bundle.config when the app is first started and just calls the same methods that you would use in the class, passing in the values it reads from the .config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this documentation explains it all better than I ever could

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

One of the nicest things is this:

> The bundling framework follows several common conventions such as:
>
> Selecting “.min” file for release when “FileX.min.js” and “FileX.js”
> exist.
>
> Selecting the non “.min” version for debug. Ignoring “-vsdoc”
> files (such as jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js), which are used only by
> IntelliSense.

Comment: The question is about ASP.Net WebForms yet you gave him a link to ASP.Net MVC. They have different APIs and different ways of bundling. And, as Elezar said, you don't really answer the question at all.

Answer (score 23):

As far as I can tell, the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question at all. It discusses the benefits of the bundling framework, but not how using the BundleConfig.cs is different than using the bundle.config file.

A lot of it comes down to whether you prefer working in code or in markup, but each does have some pros that are specific to that method.

For the bundle.config, there's really only a single benefit, but it is a big one. By using it, you can manage bundles without having to touch code at all. This means that you can make changes without recompiling, making quick deployments easier. Also, it means that your front-end developer, who is going to be most familiar with the files that should be bundled, can define the bundles without having to work with any back-end code.

However, there are quite a few limitations on what you can specify in the Bundle.config. For instance, you can't specify any custom transformations to be applied to individual items or bundles. The only bundle properties that you're able to set are the `Path`, `CdnPath`, and `CdnFallbackExpression`. You can't set the `Orderer` or `EnableFileExtensionReplacements` properties. You don't have a way to include a directory including all subdirectories (like you can with the `IncludeDirectory` method). Basically, there's a LOT of functionality that is only available through the back-end code. Granted, a lot of this you could set by using back-end code to retrieve a bundle that was defined in the bundle.config, and then manipulating. But if you're going to do that, you might as well create the bundle in the back-end, also.

My personal philosophy is to use bundle.config unless I need to do something with the bundle that's not possible that way. However, I do agree that having them all in one place is ideal. If I decide I need to use the class, then I'll use that for **all** of my bundles of that type (I do sometimes put my JS bundles in the class and my CSS bundles in the .config file, though). I'm sure some completely reasonable people would disagree with that process, though.

Comment: Config file is considered back-end code. I have that confirmed by many front-end developers who consider anything not accessible to the browser is back-end assets.

Comment: Also, writing the code explicitly allows you to know exactly when the code is executed, set break points, inspect the input, output and other environment variables. Using bundle.config is recommended, but code is more flexible (put inside IF/ELSE), and even testable.

Comment: @Believe2014 - the point is more that it's a back-end asset file, containing information about front-end assets (JS/CSS), which the front-end developers would like to access. It's also written in a language familiar (or more familiar than C# or VB) to front-end developers.

Comment: We follow the philosophy of "*.cs is controlled by developers" while "*.config can be used by sysadmins" i.e. should a sysadmin need to change things the *.config gives them a way of making a change without needing to contact the developer / re-compile / re-publish

Comment: And FYI It appears that <webopt:BundleReference /> doesn't render scriptBundle references in Bundle.config correctly. It appears to apply Styles.Render instead of Scripts.Render. So you need to force it using <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"><%: Scripts.Render("~/myScriptBundlePath") %></asp:PlaceHolder>

Answer (score 7):

> Can anyone explain the difference in the use of bundling resources
>   using the BundleConfig.cs class file as opposed to the bundle.config
>   xml file?

The difference is that you would have to read, parse and load the content of the bundle.config at runtime. Hence, using BundleConfig.cs class file could be simpler.

> 1) why you wouldn't just do them both one particular way for simplicity

Totally agree.

> 2) why anyone would prefer to hard-code resources like that in a class file?

Simply put: easy to understand.

> It seems like a much more dynamic approach to just put them in an xml
>   file that can be changed on-the-fly if necessary.

Yes, but you have to write more code to detect when changes happen and then add/remove/replace existing setup. If done poorly, it could lead to UI issues at runtime.

> Also, if there is any real documentation on System.Web.Optimization, I
>   would love to know the location (because I sure can't find it).

Already answered above, but I would repeat: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: **You** don't need to write code to detect changes, add/remove/replace, or parse the .config file. The framework does that for you. Also, I personally think that a single XML file with all the resources is much easier to understand than code the specifies them.