# Transpile jsx to js and bundle it in bundleconfig.json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm trying to set up a ReactJS.NET project in an ASP.NET Core Applikation and bundle my jsx-files, but it seems to be harder than i expected. Now I have read tons of articles and looked through the [documentation](https://reactjs.net/) on thier site, but i doesn't help me much, when this 'guide' only works for a cs-file and mine is a json-file:`bundleconfig.json`. I also tried [this tutorial](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html), but i didn't help me.

When i go into the `bundleconfig.json`-file i try to give `outputFileName` a jsx value, and then i tells me, that the value needs to be either css or js. Do i have to transpile it somehow? Can I do this in another/a better way or do I just have to forget about bundleing my files in this project?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Related [(`*.cs` vs `*.json`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001282/1175496)

Comment: For anyone else coming across this question, there is now a much simpler way to get React to work with ASP.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli